# How to edit theme colors in TextMate 2?

Tags: textmate

In TextMate 1 there is a `Fonts & Colors` tab in `Preferences` to edit theme colors, but in TextMate 2 I cannot find how to do the same...

I can select a theme in the `View` menu, but I want to customize a theme, the same way it was possible in TextMate 1, by selecting the "scope" and changing the color with a palette and the font style.

Where is this function in TextMate 2?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Option 1: use TextMate 1:

```
open ~/Library/Application\ Support/Avian/Bundles/Themes.tmbundle/Themes/Custom.tmTheme -a TextMate
cp ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Themes/Custom.tmTheme \
~/Library/Application\ Support/Avian/Bundles/Themes.tmbundle/Themes/Custom.tmTheme
```

Option 2: edit the theme as an old-style plist from the bundle editor:

[image]

Option 3: edit the tmTheme file directly by opening it with `mate`:

```
mate ~/Library/Application\ Support/Avian/Bundles/Themes.tmbundle/Themes/Custom.tmTheme
```

The last two options require you to close and reopen files to make them use the edited theme. `tell app "TextMate 2" to reload bundles` does not work.

You can use `pl` and `plutil` to convert between the XML and old style formats:

```
pl -input file.plist -output file.plist
plutil -convert xml1 file.plist
```

Comment: This answer is 5 years old, is it still the right answer?

Comment: Well, it's now 2019 and TextMate STILL doesn't have a theme editor.  This is a glaring omission and major con for the application.

Answer (score 6):

Theme tweaking of the type you could do in TextMate 1 is not yet featured in TextMate 2 itself. HOWEVER... I just came across [this very cool online TextMate theme editor](http://thechangelog.com/tmtheme-editor-color-scheme-editor/). Its interface imitates the Fonts & Colors tab in the TM1 preferences. It apparently only works in Chrome, but I use Chrome anyway so I'm off to play with it.